# ORA-01722 : Doctrine QueryBuilder with Oracle

Tags: php, oracle, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have some troubles with the doctrine DBAL QueryBuilder.
I try to do a simple select on a table with only one param (as follow) :

```php
$qb = $newfac->createQueryBuilder();
$qb
    ->select('MOISREFERENCE', 'CODEMETIEROPERE', 'UOT', 'ENVIRONNEMENT', 'HOSTNAME', 'CODEAPPLICATION', 'NBUOT', 'NBUOTPONDERES', 'UNITE', 'CATALOGUE')
    ->where($qb->expr()->eq('MOISREFERENCE', ':mois_reference'))
    ->setParameter('mois_reference', intval($moisReference))
    ->from($this->newfac_view)
;
```

When I run this query I get this error :

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT MOISREFERENCE, CODEMETIEROPERE, UOT, ENVIRONNEMENT, HOSTNAME, CODEAPPLICATION, NBUOT, NBUOTPONDERES, UNITE, CATALOGUE FROM newfac2013.HISTO_VOLUMES WHERE MOISREFERENCE = ?' with params [201508]:

ORA-01722: invalid number
```

And when I run this from DataGrip or SQLDeveloper it works perfectly even if i remove the where clause.
Any idea ?

Comment: What is the data type of `newfac2013.HISTO_VOLUMES.MOISREFERENCE`?

Comment: @BobJarvis `NUMBER(*)`

Comment: @BobJarvis apparently this error is caused by `NBUOT` column, which contains values like `0.021694183349609375`, `10.26806640625`, `4.355678558349609375`. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: `ORA-01722: invalid number` indicates that the database is attempting to convert a string to a number, and found that the string contains non-numeric characters.

Comment: It comes from the view i was query wasn't well formed ... sry